# Take and improve time for Views in Django

Tags: django, debugging, django-views, newrelic

I am looking for a tool that can show me which view is taking more time to execute in my development environment. I have used [New Relic](http://www.newrelic.com) to monitoring apps in production; it shows a very nice view for every class (view). Is there a tool like this for development? Considering there is no much data and concurrency while developing.

I have also used django-debug-toolbar but I don't know why it makes my app run very slow... and it show the time for view rendering the page, some times it is just a TemplateView extending from other classes, I need something more detailed.

Comment: Give a try to the Django-debug-toolbar, it shows you the processing time of your views and  sql querys (which (most of the time) are the bottleneck of a web app)

Comment: Have you tried enabling the ProfilingPanel of the toolbar:  http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/panels.html#profiling